# Difference between two methods of random point generation

Tags: python, simulation, uniform

In order to do a monte carlo simulation to estimate expected distance between two random points in $n$ dimensional space I discovered the following two similar looking methods to generate random points seem to differ. I'm not able to figure out why.

Method 1:

```
def expec_distance1(n, N = 10000):
  u = uniform(0,1)
  dist = 0
  for i in range(N):

      x = np.array([u.rvs() for i in range(n)])
      y = np.array([u.rvs() for i in range(n)])

      dist = (dist*i + euclidean_dist(x,y))/(i+1.0)
  return dist
```

Method 2:

```
def expec_distance2(n, N = 10000):

  u = uniform(0,1)
  dist = 0
  for i in range(N):

      x = u.rvs(n)
      y = u.rvs(n)

      dist = (dist*i + euclidean_dist(x,y))/(i+1.0)
  return dist
```

where uniform distribution is `scipy.stats.uniform` and `np` stands for numpy.

For 100 runs of the two methods (for n = 2), with method 1, I get $\mu = 0.53810011995126483, \sigma = 0.13064091613389378$
with method 2, $\mu = 0.52155615672453093, \sigma = 0.0023768774304696902$

Why is there such a  big difference between std dev of two methods?

Here is the code to try: 
https://gist.github.com/swairshah/227f056e6acee07db6778c3ae746685b
(I've replaced scipy with numpy, cause its faster but it has the same difference between std dev)

Comment: related comments are from first answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52909/how-to-find-the-expected-distance-between-two-uniformly-distributed-points?rq=1. But the reason why they are different is not provided

Comment: Can you post a full, runnable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: @MikeGraham added to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, list comprehensions leak their loop variables.

Since you're looping over `i` in your list comprehensions (`[u.rvs() for i in range(n)]`), that is the `i` used in `dist = (dist*i + euclidean_dist(x,y))/(i+1.0)`. (`i` always equals `n-1` rather than the value of the main loop variable.)

Comment: Blech, I figured it out 12 minutes too late. Stupid Python scoping.

Comment: This is fixed in python 3, which is great.